# Visual studio 2010 pre-build event to compile & deploy a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pre-build-event

i need to set a pre-build event in visual studio that will build and deploy a solution.  the separate solution is in a directory below the current directory of the solution that i am working in.  does that make sense?

```
           top level dir
          /          \
         /            \
        /              \
 |------------|    |-----------------|
 | mySLn.sln  |    |prebuild sln dir |
 |------------|    |-----------------|
                          \
                           \
                            \
                   |-----------------|
                   |  prebuild.sln   |
                   |-----------------|
```

the problem is that we have multiple developers so to use a absolute path for the solution will not work.  we will have to manually update the path per develoepr per dev server.  is there for the developers to have a pre-build event to build and deploy the prebuild.sln from visual studio 2010 with a relative path?
everything i see online is full path for:
devenv /build
devenv /deploy

is there a variable i can grab for the full path that the current solution is in and append my subdirectory and solution to the devenv command for a full path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got two options:

The first is to fix the structure of the solutions, and add project references to the projects in mySln.sln. (To do this you'd have to add the sub-projects to the solution, then add the project references. You can then remove the sub-projects from mySln.sln if you want.)

The second option is to build the projects in prebuild solution. You then setup [reference paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6taasyc6.aspx) in the projects where you need to reference the pre-build output, and then add references to the dlls. Visual studio will store the paths to the dlls in the *.csproj.user files. Then, each time a developer pulls a new version of the mySln.sln they will need to go through and set-up the reference paths in the projects, but they *wont* need to setup the references themselves. Your pre-build solution can then live anywhere, or indeed be built on a CI server and the output downloaded as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This macro is available in the Build Event command line:

$(SolutionDir)

Comment: Devenv $(SolutionDir)Common\Common.sln /Build Release
getting the "exited with code 9009"